# How to do button parallel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried so many ways to parallel for those two buttons.Two buttons are parallel if I remove html.beginform. My problem is that I can't remove html.beginform. Please show me the right direction.

html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportExcel", "SalesByBranch", FormMethod.Post@*, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }*@))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Excel" id="btnExcel" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control" onclick=DataCheck(); style="width:80px;height:30px;" />
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportPDF", "SalesByBranch", FormMethod.Post@*, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }*@))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="PDF" id="btnPDF" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm form-control" onclick=DataCheck(); style="width:80px;height:30px;" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz3lj.jpg)

Please reply me.

Comment: I believe you have some problem with your form tag, maybe display: block on the form tag? Can you post the outputed html code? And maybe the relevant css?

Comment: Ok !! I will try it. Thank for your answer. :D

Comment: see here:https://jsfiddle.net/ekxt5pom/5/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the buttons inside a div with the following style:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Ok !! I will try it. Thank for your answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

So? http://jsfiddle.net/3aowjLc1/

```
display:inline block
```

You must add agin your "script".

Comment: Ok !! I will try it. Thank for your answer. :D